# show taskbar icons in opened order

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, taskbar, icons

When I open programs (in Windows 7) I want the icons in the task bar to be ordered as in XP (first program opened is the first item/icon in the taskbar). If I open Internet Explorer and Notepad, the first icon is Internet Explorer and the second is Notepad. BUT if I download something, then the second icon becomes Internet Explorer download window and the 3rd is Notepad. Is there any option/setting to correct that (I want to make the Internet Explorer download window to become the 3rd icon in the taskbar)

I hope my example gives you an idea of what I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Windows 7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/?proj=29) can fix this easily, it sounds like the buttons are currently being grouped by application id, which is the default behavior. Under **Grouping** change it to **Don't group** and hit Apply.

[image]

If you are looking for the Windows XP/Vista behavior with regards to the look, the How-To Geek has [an article on that](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3784/change-the-windows-7-taskbar-to-work-like-vista/).

Comment: location: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\,
key: TaskbarGlomming,
value: 0=not grouped, 1 = grouped

Comment: Yep, it just modifies registry keys. I like to keep things simple for people just in case, but if you are comfortable with the registry go for it! :)

Comment: I forgot that option and I didn't know what to search for... I hate when that happens...